# What's the difference between two PID processes?

Tags: top

What's the difference between the two processes here, they both have similar files and dir inside them?

[image: Two Different PID]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting. https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Comment: They have a different number... so they are different processes. Does not mean they can not have the same files. So I do not understand the question.

Comment: My point being, if all the files are same then how are the processes different. Isn't it the same copy of process ?- @Rinzwind

Answer (score 0):

The `/proc` filesystem is used for "housekeeping" of the processes, containing meta-information about each process. Read more details here:

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html

If you're looking for the files **opened** by each process you should use the [`lsof`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsof.8.html) command.